# extjs deployment - order of file loading

Tags: ajax, extjs, extjs4, web-deployment

i've reached the stage where's my extjs web app is ready for deployment, and using the sencha CMD i've created the jsb file, with which i created the all-classes.js and all-app.js.  but when i tried to run the deployed version it fails - i understand why, but i don't know how to fix it.
you see, my app.js file of the application looks like this;

```
var SessionData = null;
var Proxy = null;    

Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', function (conn, response) {
    if (response.status === 401) {
        window.location.href = "../login/index.html";
    }
    if (response.status === 403) {
        var data = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Error', data.error);
    }
});
....
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url :'/LPAA/Servlets/servlet/LPA',
    method: 'GET',
    params: {
        action: App.Actions.UserManagement.VALIDATE,
        lpCode: getJsonFromUrl().lpParentCode
    },
    scope: this,
    success: onValidateSession,
    failure: function(){
        window.location.href = "../login/index.html";
    }
});
....
function onValidateSession(response){
    SessionData = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
    if (SessionData == null || SessionData.userName == null){
        window.location.href = "../login/index.html";
        return;
    }
    Proxy = {
        type: 'ajax',
        url :'/LPAA/Servlets/servlet/LPA',
        timeout:120000,
        reader: {
            root: "array",
            type: 'json'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    };
    Ext.Loader.setConfig({
        enabled: true,
        disableCaching: false // this prevents break-points in Chrome's debugger to     disappear after reloading the page
    });

    Ext.application({
        requires: [...],
        models: [...],
        stores: [...],
        views: [...],
        controllers: [...],
        name: 'LPAClient',
        launch: function () {
            globalApp = this;
            Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
                layout: 'fit',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'entitlement'
                   }
               ]
            });
            try {
                Ext.create('LPAClient.GeneralUtils');
            } catch (ex){}
        }
    });
}
```

the point is that first the session is validated through the server, and only if its valid the application is constructed.  now when i run the app, the error i get in the browser's console is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined
```

which origin is in the `Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception'...` in the beginning of the code.  i can see in the network's tab the the app-all.js is loaded ahead of the Ajax.js file.
how can i force my application to load the Ajax.js file before it loads the all-app.js file? or in other words - how can i  have the app.js require 'Ext.Ajax' before it uses it?

cheers,
eRez

Comment: Did you try to use `sencha app build` instead of the `jsb` way ? jsb was recommended for ExtJS 3, but it is deprecated for ExtJs 4.

Comment: i used the 'sencha build' command as explained here - [link]http://existdissolve.com/2011/08/extjs-4-my-first-build/[link]  did you mean something else?  if so  - what was it?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer is right. It's very easy to deploy extjs4 projects by using the [Sencha CMD](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download) if you have generated your project using this. All you have to do is to execute commands `sencha app build` then `sencha app build production` and you're good to deploy your project.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem with your code is that you should not run ExtJS code outside of your application. Put your session verification code into the `launch` method of your application. This is more consistent with the new MVC paradigm in ExtJs.

About sencha cmd:
Sencha cmd version 4 is aware of all javascript files your app use, and you don't need to maintain a jsb file any more. Read the [introduction to Sencha Cmd here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/command) and the [complete Sencha Command 4.0 docs](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/4.0.0/#!/guide).

The `jsb3` way to compile an app was used with Sencha Command 3.0 and works in version 4.0 for backwards compatibility reasons, but it is discouraged. The reference you mention is already older than two year and is outdated now, because it was written before the release of Sencha cmd 4.0.

I cannot explain how to migrate a project to the new way of thinking ExtJs. Steps involved are cerainly:

- Ensure that each JS file contains only one class definition and that it is in the path corresponding to the class name it contains.
- Review your folder structure according to the [recommendations](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/application_architecture):

  app/
      model/
      store/
      controller/
      view/
      Application.js
  index.html
  app.js